# What is a word for a decision-making time saver?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say you have to make a decision which has so many choices that it would be infeasible to think about them all. What is the word for a decision-making technique that would cut down on a lot or most of the extra options such that you are only left with a few or one?

Answer (score 1):

A decision-making mental shortcut is called a '[heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic)', which is close to what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about *heuristic*?

M-W:

> [*heuristic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heuristic):
>   involving or serving as an aid to learning, discovery, or
>   problem-solving by experimental and especially trial-and-error methods

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic):

> A heuristic technique (/hjᵿˈrɪstᵻk/; Ancient Greek: εὑρίσκω, "find" or
>   "discover"), often called simply a heuristic, is any approach to
>   problem solving, learning, or discovery that employs a practical
>   method not guaranteed to be optimal or perfect, but sufficient for the
>   immediate goals. **Where finding an optimal solution is impossible or
>   impractical, heuristic methods can be used to speed up the process of
>   finding a satisfactory solution.** Heuristics can be mental shortcuts
>   that ease the cognitive load of making a decision. Examples of this
>   method include using a rule of thumb, an educated guess, an intuitive
>   judgment, stereotyping, profiling, or common sense. [emphasis added]

Comment: I think the OP should have a go at prioritizing all those choices he's faced with. Rich, the cryptic reference to cheeseburger has me somewhat discombobulated!

Comment: @PeterPoint John Belushi, Saturday Night Live, "Cheeseburger, cheeseburger." Time to call it a night! More tomorrow. What?

Comment: Huge fan of John Belushi but we never got Saturday Night Live on the telly in dear old blighty. We made do with the Burns & Allen Show in B&W. Till tomorrow, ol' chum.